# Replacing dashes and comas in panads DF

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to Pandas and I'm struggling to convert the several columns dtypes from objects to float. The columns I want to convert have both dashes "-" and commas e.g. "10,000".

Is there a quick and easy way so select these certain columns, and replace any dashes with 0's and remove the commas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: SVP give some examples of this. Nb that `read_csv` has a thousands parameter, set `thousands=','`

Comment: Hello there, welcome to stackoverflow. I sugget you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you fix your question, I will be glad to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` and [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
cols=['column1','column2']
df[cols] = (df[cols].replace(',|-', '.', regex=True)
                    .apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
           )
```

**Alternative:**

```
df[cols]=pd.to_numeric(df[cols].replace(',|-', '.', regex=True)
                               .stack(), errors='coerce').unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found this after some searching which seems to work also :) df[object_cols] = df[object_cols].replace({'-': '0', ',': ''}, regex=True)